# замена текста в шаблонизаторе smarty

Tags: php, html, smarty

Есть массив, где key="слова заменяемые на" item="другие слова"
У меня получалось вывести только последнию итерацию, поэтому я добавил условие, что в первой итерации берется исходная строка, а следующие итерации уже работают с измененной, чтобы поменять другие совпадение.  Но так не работает

```
<h2 class="js-replace-words">
                {assign var=arrReplace value=['Салфетки влажные'=>'штуки','что-то'=>'еще']}
                {foreach from=$arrReplace key=o item=n}
                   {if $smarty.foreach.arrReplace.first}
                      {assign var=str value=$prodnameTruncate[0]}
                   {else}
                      {assign var=str value=$str}
                   {/if}
                   {assign var=newstr value=$str|replace:$o:$n}
                {/foreach}
                {$newstr}
            </h2>
```

На js код который должен полуится в итоге, выглядит так:

```
for (var i=0; i < arrReplace.length; i++){
    var str = $('h2').text();
    var newstr = str.split(array[i].o).join(array[i].n);
    $('h2').text(newstr);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

функция `str_replace` в пхп может принимать не только строки в качестве параметров замены, но и массивы.

не знаю  на сколько целесообразно проводить саму замену в шаблоне, и может имеет смысл вынести это в слой бизнес-логики.

В дополнение к ответу @Eugen Gedroyc замечу, что переход на smarty3 позволит вам писать код куда более наглядно и понятно, и приведенный код будет выглядеть так:

```
{$arrReplace = ['Салфетки влажные'=>'штуки','что-то'=>'еще']}

{foreach $arrReplace as $o => $n}
   {if $n@first}
      {$str = $prodnameTruncate[0]}
   {else}
      {$str = $newstr}
   {/if}
   {$newstr = $str|replace:$o:$n}
{/foreach}

{$newstr}
```

в целом, если перед циклом установить начальное значение переменной, то проверки номера итераций тоже не нужны

```
{$arrReplace = ['Салфетки влажные'=>'штуки','что-то'=>'еще']}

{$str = $prodnameTruncate[0]}   
{foreach $arrReplace as $o => $n}
   {$str = $str|replace:$o:$n}
{/foreach}

{$str}
```

ну и в заключение, просто передав массивы замены в функцию все можно свести к

```
{$arrReplace = ['Салфетки влажные'=>'штуки','что-то'=>'еще']}

{$keys = $arrReplace|array_keys} 
{$values = $arrReplace|array_values}

{$prodnameTruncate[0]|replace:$keys:$values}
```

Answer (score 0):

там 2 ошибки. логическая: {assign var=str value=$str} 
и синтаксическая: не добавил "name" для foreach.
Вот так выглядит рабочий код:

```
{foreach from=$arrReplace key=o item=n name=arrReplace}
               {if $smarty.foreach.arrReplace.first}
                  {assign var=str value=$prodnameTruncate[0]}
               {else}
                  {assign var=str value=$newstr}
               {/if}
               {assign var=newstr value=$str|replace:$o:$n}
            {/foreach}
```